# Update in CRUD returns null id

Tags: java, crud, single-responsibility-principle

I have a task to refactor shopping list application so it meet SRP. The problem is with updating existing product, i have no idea how to update it within the same ID that were assigned at first. At this point it returns a null when i try to update product. How to make it update correctly with the same ID.

```
public class ProductService {

    private ProductInMemoryRepository repository = new ProductInMemoryRepository();
    private ProductValidationService validationService = new ProductValidationService();

    public Long createProduct(Product product) {
        validationService.validate(product);
        Product newProduct = repository.insert(product);
        return newProduct.getId();
    }

    public Product findProductById(Long id){
        return repository.findProductById(id);
    }

    public Product removeById(Long id){
        repository.removeProductById(id);
        return null;
    }

    public Long updateProduct(Product product){
        validationService.validate(product);
        Product newProduct = repository.update(product);
        return newProduct.getId();
    }


}
```

---

```
public class ProductInMemoryRepository {
    private long productIdSequence = 0L;
    public Map<Long, Product> productRepository = new HashMap<>();

    public Product insert(Product product) {
        product.setId(productIdSequence++);
        productRepository.put(product.getId(), product);
        return product;
    }

    public Product findProductById(Long id) {
        return productRepository.get(id);
    }

    public Long removeProductById(Long id){
        productRepository.remove(id);
        return productIdSequence;
    }

    public Product update(Product product){
        productRepository.put(product.getId(),product);
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's your actual code, there's no way `updateProduct` could return anything but `product.getId()` (that is, the very one for the product you're passing as paramater), unless that's `null` to begin with.

Comment: You didn't include ProductValidationService, for the validationService.validate(product) call.

Comment: It is probable that `validationService.validate(product)` changes the product...